# How to implement Login with FaceBook in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to implement an app which uses FaceBook login to enter the app. How can I do this. I have seen few guidelines like this
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

I want to support iOS 3.0 and above. But really confused how to implement this. Can some one point some useful tutorials ?

Thanks

Comment: Use sharekit. It will solve most of your problems.

Comment: I am already using sharekit in my project. But confused how to implement login using that. Can you please give soem hints?

Comment: Basically you want someone to login to facebook. If facebook says login successful, then the user is considered to be logged in to your app as well? Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called SSO (single sign on) for Facebook.
You can use [Facebook code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample) as a starting point.

You would have a serious difficulties supporting iOS 3.x because Apple doesn't support it anymore, With the new xCode you can submit apps from 4.3 and above so consider if you want to waste your precious time debugging on something irrelevant in most cases.

Comment: The Hackbook link is no longer valid

Comment: @SimonBosley Yea, Now you can use: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample

This post is old...

Comment: Was gong to ask a similar question but also found the Facebook iOS SDK, looks like I'll give it a go at creating an SSO login for an iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app